# A-frame change sound properties onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, three.js, aframe

I have some sound in my scene using A-frame (https://aframe.io). I also have a button button at the top of my screen. What I'm wondering is how can I make it so when a button is clicked, the `rolloffFactor` of the sound is decreased from 1 to 0. Current code:

```
  <html>
          <head>
            <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function changeRollOff() {
    /*Code to change factor of roll off here*/
    }
    </script>
        </head>
          <body>
            <a-scene>
            
            <button style="position: fixed; z-index: 10000;" onclick="changeRollOff()"
            >Change RollOffactor</button>    
            
              <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
              <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
              <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
              <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
        <a-entity id="river" geometry="primitive: plane" material="color: blue"
                  position="-10 0 0" sound="src: url(https://cdn.glitch.com/2ecb29ef-7d11-4ac6-b954-e050a39aa59a%2FCHIPTUNE%2C%20BUT%20FUNKY%20Useful.mp3?v=1630627441361); autoplay: true; rolloffFactor: 1;"></a-entity>
        
              <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
            </a-scene>
          </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rolloffFactor` is a property of the `sound` attribute. You can change it with [`element.setAttribute(component, property, new_value)`](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#updating-single-property-of-multi-property-component):

```
document.getElementById("river").setAttribute("sound", "rolloffFactor", 0);
```

Comment: Sorry, I actually have one question. The code is setting the rolloffFactor by finding the <a-sound> tag but In another of my uses, the code for my  sound is actually wrapped in an entity like so:           <a-entity class="avatar" id="river" networked-audio-source="distanceModel: exponential; refDistance: 3; maxDistance: 100" >
How can I modify the code to change the rollOfffactor of the entity instead of the <a-sound> tag?

Comment: If you want to change the `networked-audio-source` you do the same thing - `document.getElementById("river").setAttribute("networked-audio-source", "rolloffFactor", 0);`

The selector is finding the entity with the `river` id, and change the desired attribute.

Comment: I tested the code and it wasn't working. I think because of the fact  that it can't find the audio for some reason since the function is running fine. Is it possible to just set the rollOffFactor to variable so that I can simply change the variable therefore changing the rollOffFactor?